# Python 3.3 input() shows no prompt and happens before prior command

Tags: python, python-3.x, notepad++, conda

I'm running python33 and here's my code:

```
print("get input")
uinp = input("get inputttt\n")
print("uinp IS: " + uinp)
```

There's absolutely nothing else in this .py file, but this code combination was causing me some trouble in another larger program.

What happens is I get a blank command line into which I can type, and then the rest of the program comes through. Example, for input 'hello world', here's what the command prompt looks like:

```
hello world
get input
get inputttt
uinp IS: hello world

C:\Program Files\Notepad++>
```

Any clues about what the problem is? My best guess is that this might be related to how I call python in Notepad++, through `"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /k conda run "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`, but how could this have as a result that problem?

Comment: Notepad++ must be buffering all output before showing it to you. It could be worse – `input` simply does not do anything inside Sublime Text, for example. Run your script in a console to see the proper behavior.

Comment: @usr2564301 ah, so it works on anaconda prompt and on simple cmd, but not on conda through cmd. thank you very much! (although.. do you know if this can be fixed?)

Comment: If you're using Anaconda, why not use Spyder as your IDE?

Comment: @S3DEV unfortunately a slow computer hahaha